# React not working on IE11 and Edge browser

Tags: reactjs, cross-browser

I am able to view my app in chrome. But when I tried in internet explorer. I am getting a blank page, and in Edge, I am getting unexpected behaviour.

What can I do to resolve these kinds of errors?

> I followed https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8379 and installed polyphils but that also didn't work out.

Comment: `What can I do to resolve these kinds of errors?` => First step would be to check your console for errors.

Comment: i already tried that i m getting 2 : ReferenceError: 'URLSearchParams' is undefined  and TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'startsWith'.

Comment: @Ionut i dont know what to do after this. Not able to understand why this error is comming that to only in IE